# Is there a way to cause compound controls to paint their border to indicate focus is within the control?

Tags: windows, delphi, controls

This question may not be specifically about Delphi; but, since that is the tool that I am using, that is how I am going to frame it.

Simple Delphi edit controls, such as `TEdit`, paint their borders in a different color when they have focus (this is under Windows 10, I think it might be a bit different under Windows 11).

Notice the thin blue border when focused:

[image]

The problem is that I have a few compound controls that I have written that contain other controls as children. The contained controls are set to `BorderStyle=bsNone` and do not indicate focus by means of their border, and I do not want them to. Instead, I want the parent control to indicate that focus is somewhere within it by changing its own border, just as `TEdit` and other simple controls do.

Is there a way to cause a compound control to paint its border to indicate focus, just as `TEdit` does, when focus is somewhere within one of its children controls?

I have tried many things. It seems that having Runtime Themes enabled plays a role in this. I have it enabled on the application, but I am not using themes.

I have researched and attempted to use the Windows API call of `DrawFocusRect()`. That does not seem to be the path to a solution, and I see no evidence that `TEdit` uses that call.

I have researched and messed with `ControlStyle`, `Style`, and `ExStyle` with no luck. The solution, if it is down one of those paths, is not apparent to me.

The only solution that I have found so far is to completely rewrite these compound controls to not be compound, and to send an `EM_SETRECTNP` message to set the edit rectangle. That only works for some of them, and is a major effort that I am hoping to avoid.

Comment: Paint it yourself using GDI.

Comment: So what is the base component of these compound controls? `TPanel`? Or something of your own creation?

Comment: They are of our own creation. With a few intermediate subclasses, it goes back to TCustomControl in the hierarchy.

Comment: Well, if you cant expand with more details on what you already have, I repeat the first comment: use GDI. Or enter '[delphi] draw rectangle on control' in the search box above, and you will get several similar questions with many good answers.

Comment: Based on my understanding of your problem there are two areas that might be the cause. One is your compound not being properly notified that one of its child components is focused. Another is your compound control not rendering the selection rectangle. You should make sure that first part of your code that is notifying your compound component about one of its child controls having focus is working reliably first.

Comment: Using one as an example, the class hierarchy is:
TActDateEdit = class(TCustomDateEdit)  // The registered control
TCustomDateEdit = class(TActCustomEdit) // Abstract for data aware and not
TActCustomEdit = class(TCustomControl) // Abstract for variety of other controls

Comment: @SilverWarior, I am being notified of focus both entering and leaving child components. You are right that I am not rendering the selection rectangle. I don't want to render within the window, I want the border to change like it does with TEdit; and I want it to do so in the way that works for Windows 10 and Windows 11. I am starting to think that I may not be asking the right question. How does TEdit cause its border to change when focus enters? I can find no such code. Is it behavior in the standard control that Delphi specifies with CreateSubclass during CreateParams?

Comment: `TEdit` is one of the focusable controls therefore it has its own internal routines for rendering its focus rectangle. But since you are trying to get focus rectangle to what I believe is non focusable control you will have to make your own routines that will take care of rendering the desired focus rectangle.

Comment: `TEdit` does it itself in the underlyiing Windows EDIT control. I'm not sure why you're wanting to do this, though. It isn't standard behavior for a Windows GUI, and IMO will confuse users because they'll have no idea which control inside that area will receive their input. Windows users are expecting the control that will receive their keystrokes to be highlighted to indicate so.